# Can I move an ad unit to another app without losing my money in AdMob?

Tags: admob

I want to move an ad unit from an app to another app (This app contains Banner Ads) in [AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/), this unit (the one which I want to move it) is for Interstitial Ads, and after that I will update my app. My question here, can I move the ad unit without losing my money?!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because you should ask Admob directly.

Comment: @Andy Can you tell me, where I can ask them, or can I find a FAQ for that?! :)

Comment: If there's money involved, there must be a "contact us" link somewhere...

Comment: why you don't want to create a new ad unit ?

Answer (score 0):

AdUnitIds are linked to your published account. So you can have one or more AdUnitIds on the same publisher account.

So to be specific, you can move that AdUnitId to your other app.
Downside is that you will probably get less well defined ads if you are using that AdUnitId is 2 different apps.